# dummy nested ifelse error problem with mutate

Tags: r

Good morning all,

I am trying to create and add dummy variables as followed to my current dataset however it is not working.

```
cwcl_dummy<- cwcl_no%>%
  mutate(P_Doming_Membrane = ifelse(Product == "Doming", 1, ifelse(Product == "Membrane Switches", 1,0))) %>%
  mutate(Distributors =ifelse(Industry == "Distributors", 1, 0))
```

cwcl_no% exists and works, also as an error I have:

```
Problem with `mutate()` input `Distributors`. x object 'Industry' not found i Input `Distributors` is `ifelse(Industry == "Distributors", 1, 0)`.
```

here is my dataset:

```
'data.frame':   13339 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Company_ID       : num  1.32e+08 4.09e+08 1.29e+08 1.29e+08 1.29e+08 ...
 $ Deal_ID          : num  2.81e+09 2.78e+09 2.79e+09 2.79e+09 2.79e+09 ...
 $ Amount           : num  2132 2035 1992 3607 3002 ...
 $ Industries       : chr  "Business & Service" "Business & Service" "Distributors" "Business & Service" ...
 $ Product          : chr  "OSP Misc" "OSP Misc" "OSP Misc" "Doming" ...
 $ Close_Lost_reason: chr  "N/A" "N/A" "N/A" "N/A" ...
```

I am not doing any dataset manipulation prior to that.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your column name is called `Industries` and you are using `Industry` in second `ifelse`. You can also simplify your logic without using `ifelse`.

```
library(dplyr)

cwcl_dummy <- wcl_no %>%
            mutate(P_Doming_Membrane = as.integer(Product %in% c("Doming", "Membrane Switches")) 
            Distributors = as.integer(Industries == "Distributors"))
```